# MVC Entity Framework invalid column name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working with MVC 4 and Entity Framework to create a web app recently. Things have been going well with my database "ppProject" model, as shown here:

```
Public Class ppProject
    <Key()>
    Public Property ProjectID As Integer
    Public Property ClientID As Integer
    Public Property ProjectTitle As String

    Public Overridable Property Client As ppClient
    Public Overridable Property Milestones As ICollection(Of ppMilestone)
    Public Overridable Property Tasks As ICollection(Of ppTask)
End Class
```

The problem is that I am adding a new table of employees, "ppEmployees". This way the Project can have a ProjectManager, which is a foreign key into the Employees table. These are the new models where ProjectManagerID (foreign key) is linked to EmployeeID (primary key):

```
Public Class ppProject
    <Key()>
    Public Property ProjectID As Integer
    Public Property ClientID As Integer
    Public Property ProjectTitle As String
    Public Property ProjectManagerID As Integer   'NEW'

    Public Overridable Property Client As ppClient
    Public Overridable Property Milestones As ICollection(Of ppMilestone)
    Public Overridable Property Tasks As ICollection(Of ppTask)
    Public Overridable Property ProjectManager As ppEmployee   'NEW'
End Class

Public Class ppEmployee
    <Key()>
    Public Property EmployeeID As Integer
    Public Property DepartmentID As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String

    Public Overridable Property ProjectsInManagement As ICollection(Of ppProject)
    Public Overridable Property TimeItems As ICollection(Of ppTimeItem)
    Public Overridable Property Department As ppDepartment
End Class
```

When I change my project model and add the employee model, I am getting the error

> Invalid column name 'ProjectManager_EmployeeID'

The line of code that is triggering this is when I first access my projects in a view with:

```
@For Each proj In client.Projects
```

Any ideas at what is causing this? This must be a naming convention problem or something simple because I haven't had any errors with any of my other table models prior to this.

**EDIT -** See my answer below. Very confused about what Entity Framework is doing here.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework the name of the field must match the name of the column.

otherwise EF wouldnt know how to map the fields unless you decorate the property with the column attribute like you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've fixed this. I had to make the following changes to the "ppProject" class:

```
<Column("ProjectManagerID")>
Public Property EmployeeID As Nullable(Of Integer) 'Has to be set, dont know why
```

If anyone knows why my property has to be named EmployeeID, please let me know. I'm very curious.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem about a month ago. I dropped the table and created a new one and the problem was solved. that is after i have tried other ways that did not work